# Scipy Fast 1-D interpolation without any loop

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I have two 2D array, x(ni, nj) and y(ni,nj), that I need to interpolate over one axis. I want to interpolate along last axis for every ni.

I wrote

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

z = np.asarray([200,300,400,500,600])
out = []
for i in range(ni):
    f = interp1d(x[i,:], y[i,:], kind='linear')
    out.append(f(z))
out = np.asarray(out)
```

However, I think this method is inefficient and slow due to loop if array size is too large. What is the fastest way to interpolate multi-dimensional array like this? Is there any way to perform linear and cubic interpolation without loop? Thanks.

Comment: Have you done any profiling on your code?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The method you propose does have a python loop, so for large values of `ni` it is going to get slow. That said, unless you are going to have large `ni` you shouldn't worry much.

I have created sample input data with the following code:

```
def sample_data(n_i, n_j, z_shape) :
    x = np.random.rand(n_i, n_j) * 1000
    x.sort()
    x[:,0] = 0
    x[:, -1] = 1000
    y = np.random.rand(n_i, n_j)
    z = np.random.rand(*z_shape) * 1000
    return x, y, z
```

And have tested them with this two versions of linear interpolation:

```
def interp_1(x, y, z) :
    rows, cols = x.shape
    out = np.empty((rows,) + z.shape, dtype=y.dtype)
    for j in xrange(rows) :
        out[j] =interp1d(x[j], y[j], kind='linear', copy=False)(z)
    return out

def interp_2(x, y, z) :
    rows, cols = x.shape
    row_idx = np.arange(rows).reshape((rows,) + (1,) * z.ndim)
    col_idx = np.argmax(x.reshape(x.shape + (1,) * z.ndim) > z, axis=1) - 1
    ret = y[row_idx, col_idx + 1] - y[row_idx, col_idx]
    ret /= x[row_idx, col_idx + 1] - x[row_idx, col_idx]
    ret *= z - x[row_idx, col_idx]
    ret += y[row_idx, col_idx]
    return ret
```

`interp_1` is an optimized version of your code, following Dave's answer. `interp_2` is a vectorized implementation of linear interpolation that avoids any python loop whatsoever. Coding something like this requires a sound understanding of broadcasting and indexing in numpy, and some things are going to be less optimized than what `interp1d` does. A prime example being finding the bin in which to interpolate a value: `interp1d` will surely break out of loops early once it finds the bin, the above function is comparing the value to all bins.

So the result is going to be very dependent on what `n_i` and `n_j` are, and even how long your array `z` of values to interpolate is. If `n_j` is small and `n_i` is large, you should expect an advantage from `interp_2`, and from `interp_1` if it is the other way around. Smaller `z` should be an advantage to `interp_2`, longer ones to `interp_1`.

I have actually timed both approaches with a variety of `n_i` and `n_j`, for `z` of shape `(5,)` and `(50,)`, here are the graphs:

[image]

[image]

So it seems that for `z` of shape `(5,)` you should go with `interp_2` whenever `n_j < 1000`, and with `interp_1` elsewhere. Not surprisingly, the threshold is different for `z` of shape `(50,)`, now being around `n_j < 100`. It seems tempting to conclude that you should stick with your code if `n_j * len(z) > 5000`, but change it to something like `interp_2` above if not, but there is a great deal of extrapolating in that statement! If you want to further experiment yourself, here's the code I used to produce the graphs.

```
n_s = np.logspace(1, 3.3, 25)
int_1 = np.empty((len(n_s),) * 2)
int_2 = np.empty((len(n_s),) * 2)
z_shape = (5,)

for i, n_i in enumerate(n_s) :
    print int(n_i)
    for j, n_j in enumerate(n_s) :
        x, y, z = sample_data(int(n_i), int(n_j), z_shape)
        int_1[i, j] = min(timeit.repeat('interp_1(x, y, z)',
                                        'from __main__ import interp_1, x, y, z',
                                        repeat=10, number=1))
        int_2[i, j] = min(timeit.repeat('interp_2(x, y, z)',
                                        'from __main__ import interp_2, x, y, z',
                                        repeat=10, number=1))

cs = plt.contour(n_s, n_s, np.transpose(int_1-int_2))
plt.clabel(cs, inline=1, fontsize=10)
plt.xlabel('n_i')
plt.ylabel('n_j')
plt.title('timeit(interp_2) - timeit(interp_1), z.shape=' + str(z_shape))
plt.show()
```

Comment: @Tetsuro If you find the answer useful, you can upvote it by clicking the up arrow close the header of the answer. Also, if you feel that it answers your question, you can accept it by clicking on the outlined check mark.

Comment: It's already a great answer. It would be even better if there was a short outline on how  `interp_2` is working. (Perhaps not line-by-line, but in general, what the approach is of doing that interpolation)

Comment: Could it be that your linear interpolation is "only" a spline, a linear approximation through the closest grid points - instead of fitting a linear function through the whole grid?

Answer (score 2):

One optimization is to allocate the result array once like so:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

z = np.asarray([200,300,400,500,600])
out = np.zeros( [ni, len(z)], dtype=np.float32 ) 
for i in range(ni):
    f = interp1d(x[i,:], y[i,:], kind='linear')
    out[i,:]=f(z)
```

This will save you some memory copying that occurs in your implementation, which occurs in the calls to `out.append(...)`.