# numpy - scalar multiplication of column vector times row vector

Tags: python, vector, matrix, numpy

What is the best and most efficient way to solve the following in python numpy:

given a weight vector:

```
weights = numpy.array([1, 5, 2])
```

and a value vector:

```
values = numpy.array([1, 3, 10, 4, 2])
```

as result I need a matrix, which contains on each row the `values` vector scalar multiplied with the value of `weights[row]`:

```
result = [
    [1,  3, 10,  4,  2],
    [5, 15, 50, 20, 10],
    [2,  6, 20,  8,  4]
]
```

One solution which I found is the following:

```
result = numpy.array([ weights[n]*values for n in range(len(weights)) ])
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This operation is called the [outer product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product). It can be performed using [`numpy.outer()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html):

```
In [6]: numpy.outer(weights, values)
Out[6]: 
array([[ 1,  3, 10,  4,  2],
       [ 5, 15, 50, 20, 10],
       [ 2,  6, 20,  8,  4]])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can reshape `weights` to a dimention (3,1) array and then multiply it to `values`

```
weights = numpy.array([1, 5, 2])[:,None]  #column vector
values = numpy.array([1, 3, 10, 4, 2])
result = weights*values

print(result)

array([[ 1,  3, 10,  4,  2],  
      [ 5, 15, 50, 20, 10],  
      [ 2,  6, 20,  8,  4]])
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14757382/1860757) explains the `[:,None]`